# Grails Domain object read ignore some columns

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a grails domain gorm object with a string field. My database is postgresql.

The string field can contain much text data, up to 10MB.
I don't need this field always. So I wonder if it is possible to avoid to fill this column on 
MyDomain.read(1)?
Even better for me would be if I could get just the first 200 characters of the string.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate?

Comment: Yes, I am using hibernate